# Animate time-dependent 3D-function using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

Hope someone can help me. My goal is to animate a function U(x,z,t) and in particular the time evolution of the 3D-function U(x,z).
Firstly I wrote some code that discretize the time stepping and saved each "snapshot" in an array U[t] where t is an integer in {0,1,...,Nt} for some Nt number of timesteps. U[0] is the initial function and is given.
I want to remark that U[t] (t in {0,1,...,Nt} are all matrices containg numbers and are already suited to be plotted.
I now want to animate a plot such that:

1. The first image displayed in the window is U[0], i.e. the initial function with an appropriate label.
2. The window then refreshes and displays U[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u145I.gif) with an appropriate label.
3. It then repeats step (2) up to timestep Nt.

My first approach was to use only a "for cycle". Unfortunately, instead of a refreshing image, I created a sequence of different figures.
The code is:

```
for i in range(0,Nt+1):
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        ax.plot_surface(gridx, gridz, U[i],cmap='viridis', edgecolor='none')
        #gridx,gridz are created via np.meshgrid(...)
        ax.set_title("Function U at time-step " + str(i)+ ". Time "+ str(i*dt)+ "." )
        ax.set_xlabel('X')
        ax.set_ylabel('Z')
        ax.set_zlabel('u(x,z)')
plt.show()
```

Now I tried searching online and found many different examples using matplotlib.animation with FuncAnimation or just Animation. The problem is that I do not understand how to adapt the examples to my cases.
Could someone help me in this case?

Update: For the case where the function can also be a variable. I wrote the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
def Animate(gridx,gridz,Nt,Name, func,dt):
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection= "3d")
    ax.set_xlabel('X')
    ax.set_ylabel('Z')
    ax.set_zlabel(Name)

    def update(frame,fig):
        if len(fig.axes[0].collections) != 0:
            fig.axes[0].collections = []
            surf = fig.axes[0].plot_surface(gridx, gridz, func[frame], cmap= "viridis")
            ax.set_title("Function "+ Name + " at time-step " + str(frame)+ ". Time "+ str(frame*dt)+ ".", y = 1  )
        else:
            surf = fig.axes[0].plot_surface(gridx, gridz, func[frame], cmap= "viridis")
            ax.set_title("Function " + Name + " at time-step " + str(frame)+ ". Time "+ str(frame*dt)+ "." )
        fig.canvas.draw()
        return surf,
    ani =FuncAnimation(fig,update,fargs=[fig],frames = Nt+1, blit = True)
    ani.save("Gif for the function " + Name + ".gif")
    return
```

This code can be called with different functions to ease the treatment in case you need to visualize more functions.

The result is:
[Example of Gif for a function P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u145I.gif)

Answer (score 0):

I used following code to do animation by adding random z-direction displacement to surface, hope it can solve your issue. Pls read carefully the [animation tutorial](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html), and a 3d line example [3D animation lines](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_3danim.html). My solution might not be efficeint as I redraw the surface, but it should be easy to understand.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D  



fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')


def update(frame, fig):
    X = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
    Y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
    R = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2)
    # add random shift in z directions
    Z = np.sin(R)+np.random.random_sample()
    if len(fig.axes[0].collections) != 0:
        fig.axes[0].collections = []
        surf = fig.axes[0].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    else:
        surf = fig.axes[0].plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap=cm.coolwarm, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
    ax.set_zlim(-1.5, 1.5)

    fig.canvas.draw()
    return surf,
    
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, fargs=[fig], frames=5, blit=True)
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks really a lot! I also added titles for the axis. I was wondering if I could generalize the update function to: ``` def update(frame,fig,func) ``` so that I can input a general function to plot.

Comment: Why you need to pass a function call in update? Not sure this work or not, you can try based on my code, also update `fargs` accordingly.

Comment: Actually you are right... I decided to create a new function that deals with that. I'm gonna add that to my original post.

Comment: You strongly recommend trying by yourself first.